# Selectivley escape translation of certain parts/helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I use the helper method [`time_ago_in_words`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words) extensively, and it works as expected with I18n.

But in some parts of the application, I just want the default english.

Is there anyway to escape translation on selected methods/areas of an application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `I18n.with_locale` method to force a block of code under a specific locale regardless the global configuration.

```
I18n.with_locale(:en) do
  time_ago_in_words(...)
end
```

If you find yourself using this pattern frequently, you can create a specific helper.

```
def english_time_ago_in_words(*args)
  I18n.with_locale(:en) do
    time_ago_in_words(*args)
  end
end
```

You can also use `I18n.default_locale` instead of referencing `:en` directly.